# Gitlab Runner - Deployment - Keep Assets

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am trying to use GitLab Runner for deployment. However, whenever a job from the pipeline kicks in, it removes folders that are not source controlled. This means my assets/uploads folder are wiped out.

What is the best way to do a deployment where it keeps the assets/upload folder. Would it be better to move the assets/uploads folder out of the project and have an after_script that just links the folder to the project?

What have you guys done for auto deployment with folders not in source control?

Here is my current `.gitlab-ci.yml` file.

```
deploy_production:
  stage: deploy
  script:
  - echo "deploying to web server"
  - npm i --production
  environment:
    name: production
    url: MY_URL
  only:
  - master
  when: manual
```

Comment: I think you're looking for [**artifacts**](https://gitlab.com/help/user/project/pipelines/job_artifacts.md).

Comment: "Artifacts is a list of files and directories which are attached to a job
after it completes successfully." I think that means the folders would be gone already. Or am I mistaken?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What have you guys done for auto deployment with folders not in source control?

Add them to source control (with a `.gitkeep` file inside, in order for the folder to have some content)
That way, the resulting artifact keeps its (mostly) empty folders.

Comment: Well, it keeps the folder but still deletes all the assets in the folder.

Comment: @ScottDeutsch in that case, a post step with a symlink seems safer, as you mention in yur question.